# How to wait to use expo router until ready

Tags: react-native, expo

My index.js routes the user to a welcome page if they are not logged in and to the home page if they are. However, since this routing attempt is before the navigator is ready, it causes an error. (The most likely explanation from my testing). The specific error I get is attempted to navigate before mounting the root layout component. ensure the root layout component is rendering a slot, or other navigator on the first render. All other routing does work. Using Expo SDK 49 and router v2. Below is my _layout.js and index.js

_layout.js

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: 'index',
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="home" options={{}} />
      <Stack.Screen name="welcome" options={{}} />
    </Stack>
);
}
```

index.js

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Link, router} from 'expo-router';

export default function App(){
    const isLoggedIn = false;


    return (
        <View>
            { isLoggedIn ? router.replace("/home") : router.replace("/welcome") }
            <Text>Sorry, an error has occured, this page should not be visible</Text>
            <Text>Current file: index.js</Text>
            <Link href="/home">Go to default page</Link>
            
        </View>
    )

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rootNavigationState. Attach a use effect hook to the root navigation state key.

```
import { useRootNavigationState } from 'expo-router'
```

```js
const rootNavigationState = useRootNavigationState()
const navigatorReady = rootNavigationState?.key != null

useEffect(() => {
  if (!navigatorReady) return
  // It is ready! Navigate code here!
}, [navigatorReady])
```